# problem with android UI

Tags: android, user-interface

Following is the image of the UI. When the app is launched it appears to be as follows
[image]

in this i am showing the changes in timer and km variation. When the km gets varied my layout gets disturbed as follows

[image]

Following is the layout of my ui

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"  android:background="@drawable/rounded_background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip" android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
                       <TextView android:text="00:00:00" android:id="@+id/timer"  android:textSize="28dip" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:textColor="#000000"
                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:layout_marginBottom="15dip">
                        </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View android:id="@+id/separator1" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_centerVertical ="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_marginLeft="55dip" android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView android:text="0" android:id="@+id/pace"  android:textSize="17dip"  android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:lines="1" android:gravity="right" >
                            </TextView>
                            <TextView android:text="Km/hr" android:id="@+id/pace1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                      android:lines="1" android:textColor="#000000"  android:layout_marginLeft="7dip" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:layout_marginBottom="15dip">
                            </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>           

                    <View android:id="@+id/separator2" android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_width="1dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#000000" />

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <TextView android:text="0" android:id="@+id/cal"  android:textSize="20dip"  android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                                      android:layout_marginLeft="25dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="15dip">  
                            </TextView>
                            <TextView android:text="cal" android:id="@+id/cal1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                      android:textColor="#000000"  android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">               
                            </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>    
                </LinearLayout>
```

i dont want my UI to be disturbed, how to do this please help me friends......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should set `Layout_Width="50dip"` or some constant.. if u say it as wrap content it does it and layout get disturbed... I'm talking of 2 textviews which have km and cal..

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same `layout_weight` to `linearLayout5` and `linearLayout6`.

Answer (score 0):

Your views' text is centered manually by the margin. This approach isn't flexible as you can see. I'd remove those margins and set `landroid:layout_gravity="center"` instead. In addition, you should set the `android:layout_weight` for your `TextView`s `cal` and `cal1` like `0.6` and `0.4` respectively. Change the weight slightly if that doesn't fit you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Table row below to linearLayout2. In that table row use two linear Layout with orientation as vertical. For the first linear layout fixed it's width .then put the view after first linear layout & then second linear layout. TextView1 in first linear layout for the message & textview2 in linear lay2.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use **one** RelativeLayout [for efficiency](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="125dp">
    <TextView android:text="00:00:00" android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:textSize="28dp" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
    <View android:id="@+id/separator1" android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timer" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
    <TextView android:text="cal" android:id="@+id/cal1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_below="@+id/separator1" />
    <TextView android:text="0" android:id="@+id/cal"
        android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cal1"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cal1" />
    <View android:id="@+id/separator2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <TextView android:text="Km/hr" android:id="@+id/pace1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cal1" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/separator2" />
    <TextView android:text="0" android:id="@+id/pace"
        android:textSize="17dp" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cal1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pace1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```